# Need to add Middleware with google assistant

Tags: google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am setting up a sessionToken and for this I need to add a middleware in google assistant. Though same can be done easily using express but I am not sure how this can be achieved through google assistant web services.

Comment: To be clear - are you using Firebase Cloud Functions, the Built-In editor in Dialogflow, or something else?

Comment: Yes I am using Firebase cloud functions. Problem I am facing with middleware function. I am looking for a app.use() kind of function in my node web services which is built using the dialog flow structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are, fundamentally, an Express.js server under the covers, but don't expose you to all the configuration options for Express. You have a couple of options.

The simplest is to explicitly call the middleware itself inside your function. From [Google's documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#use_middleware_modules_with_cloud_functions):

> If you need to inject middleware dependencies for things like cookie support or CORS, call these within the function. For example, to enable CORS support, add the following block:

```
// Enable CORS using the `cors` express middleware.
cors(req, res, () => {
  // ...
});
```

There are also more elaborate ways to hook into the underlying Express framework. See [this stackoverflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579442/cloud-functions-for-firebase-and-express) and [this followup blog post](https://codeburst.io/express-js-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase-86ed26f9144c) for the details.

Comment: Thanks, somehow it solved my problem. Eventually we can add express server in cloud functions and this is all together solve my problem. Thanks for your reply

Comment: As noted, the links provide more information about hooking into the Express framework. If this helped you and answered your question, an upvote and/or accepting the answer are always appreciated.