# Run Apollo GraphQL Server on Google Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, graphql, google-cloud-functions, apollo-server

I want to run Apollo GraphQL server on Google Cloud Functions. It basically boils down to running an Express server with different routes I suppose. Is it possible and if yes then how? Do note that I don't wish to use any Firebase libraries for the same as highlighted here:

1) [Cloud Functions for Firebase and Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579442/cloud-functions-for-firebase-and-express)

2) https://codeburst.io/graphql-server-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase-ae97441399c0

3) https://codeburst.io/express-js-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase-86ed26f9144c

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the fantastic work by James Hegedus, this is possible. Check out https://github.com/jthegedus/firebase-gcp-examples/tree/main/deprecated/gcp-functions-graphql for the solution.

Comment: Dead link in the answer.

Comment: Also broken link

Answer (score 2):

Since the link on Raj Chaudhary's answer is dead, here is the official Google Cloud Function integration of GraphQL Server : https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/tree/master/packages/apollo-server-cloud-functions

You are able to run Apollo GraphQL server on Google Cloud Functions with it.