# Not able to read Firebase from functions using AdminSDK

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

As I have used [ExpressJs](https://expressjs.com/) in the project it might be a source of confusion. For me it worked fine, I followed [this](https://codeburst.io/express-js-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase-86ed26f9144c) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579442/cloud-functions-for-firebase-and-express#answer-43596194) links. My doubt is very straightforward. How can I access Firebase Realtime DB from cloud functions via HTTP trigger?

**What worked so far:**

- I am able to use [ExpressJs](https://expressjs.com/) in functions and do both POST and GET
  requests. I am able to send both JSON/plain-text responses.
- Initialization of admin SDK doesn't seem to throw any error.

**My code in function is as below:**

```
//use express
const express = require("express")
//get firebase functions
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
//get firebase admin sdk
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

/* Admin SDK */
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

/* Express */
const ss = express()

let bodyParser = require("body-parser")
ss.use(bodyParser.json())
ss.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

//When accessing the url http://localhost:5000/proj-b5d88/us-central1/api/, I am getting the response below.
ss.get("/", (request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello from Express on Firebase!")
})
//When accessing the url http://localhost:5000/proj-b5d88/us-central1/api/test, this request doesn't go through and returns the error.
ss.get("/test", (request, response) => {


    var result =  admin.database().ref('test/1').once('value', (snapshot) => {
        var r = snapshot.val();
        var rs = JSON.stringify(r);
        res.send(`
            <!doctype html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>test</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h1>Title ${ rs } </h1>
                </body>
            </html>`
        );
     });


  response.send(result);
})

const api = functions.https.onRequest(ss)

module.exports = {
  api
}
```

The base url works and returns "Hello from Express on Firebase!", however the one that connects to firebase don't. It returns the below error.

```
{"error":{"code":500,"status":"INTERNAL","message":"function crashed","errors":["connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:65373"]}}
```

**Update:**
For me the http trigger is working fine. The part thats throwing error is below:

```
  var result =  admin.database().ref('test/1').once('value', (snapshot) => {
        var r = snapshot.val();
        var rs = JSON.stringify(r);
        res.send(`
            <!doctype html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>test</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h1>Title ${ rs } </h1>
                </body>
            </html>`
        );
     });
```

**Note:**

I am triggering the function via HTTP trigger. When the user accesses the URL I want to do some operations on Drupal.

1. Do functions automatically pick the DB from the project? I haven't specified such a configuration anywhere.
2. I am running firebase function with the following command in localhost `firebase serve --only functions`. Would that be an issue?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?  You haven't specified any triggers for deployment.  You can't just run arbitrary node code on Cloud Functions.  The only way Cloud Functions works is through triggers the respond to changes in your project, or incoming HTTP requests.

Comment: `/test` is an http endpoint. I am trying to change some values when the http request is received. I am getting the http request and am able to give a response. However am not able to read from firebase.

Comment: @DougStevenson Please see, https://codeburst.io/express-js-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase-86ed26f9144c & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579442/cloud-functions-for-firebase-and-express#answer-43596194

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I said in my answer.

Comment: @DougStevenson I updated my question further. I am not understanding whats wrong in my way of access Firebase. Should I define my project, key or something  before referring to DB? I assumed its already taken care by the project itself.

Comment: @DougStevenson Updated question & code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use third party software to listen for incoming HTTP requests (or any sort of request for that matter) in Cloud Functions.  If you want to create an API endpoint, you will need to [write an HTTP trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).  There are plenty examples of doing this, and you can also use Express to set up routes on that endpoint.

Comment: I think my use of expressjs is source of confusion. I am using http trigger via ExpressJs. I followed this url for the same: https://codeburst.io/express-js-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase-86ed26f9144c.

All this is working for me. My doubt is mostly on how to access/modify firebase database after the http trigger invokes a function. Http trigger is working fine.

Comment: You never defined an HTTPS function in your code.  It would never work as shown.  The links you provided are all showing HTTPS functions defined with the SDK.  Use those patterns instead.  You can't use express to listen on some port - that's why you're getting the error message you've shown.  It has nothing to do with the database.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. I am not understanding the issue. For me I am getting response for http request if I return just some text when accessing the url via browser. Error is only there when I add the db ref to get data.

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you're defining your HTTP trigger.  As it's shown right now, there is none.  Start with the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

Comment: As suggested, I updated the code as it is in my function.